# Convivencia de jQuery y Reactjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Hace tiempo que intento realizar proyectos utilizando React.

Un amigo me preguntó si debía utilizar jQuery con React y le dije que no, porque siempre he leído que es mejor evitar jQuery y sobre todo si estamos trabajando con React.

Entonces me preguntó, ¿por qué no? Y la verdad es que no supe responderle. Siempre me he guiado por estos comentarios de no usarlo, de que no tiene futuro, etc. Pero la realidad es que no encontré un argumento demasiado coherente, salvo la ventaja de la iteración de elementos (por ejemplo), en jQuery: `$('li').on('click', function() {...})` que escribir en JS puro:

```
Array.from(
    document.queryAll('li')
).forEach(li => 
    li.addEventListener('click', function() { ... }
);
```

Entonces, ¿por qué se recomienda no utilizar jQuery? ¿Por qué no es aconsejable utilizarlo con React?

Comment: A pesar de que jQuery ha estado en decadencia estos años, sigue siendo una excelente librería para solucionar ciertos problemas, la razón por la cual la gente tal ves dice que no se debe de usar en React, es debido a la gran evolución que ha tenido javacript, que hace que no sea necesario hacer uso de jQuery. Todo depende del programador, si dominas jQuery y te gusta, no veo por que no utilizarlo. Este es mi punto de vista, no espero que sea igual al de los demas. Saludos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Principalmente es porque JQuery (y otros plugins o componentes que dependan de JQuery) modifican el DOM directamente.
Por otro lado, React mantiene una versión ligera del DOM en memoria, que es donde se mantiene el estado de sus componentes y se realizan las modificaciones pertinentes, para eventualmente poder hacer un render de estos cambios en la página (vale mencionar, ésto en términos de rendimiento es bastante superior a modificar directamente el DOM).
Como JQuery modifica el DOM ya renderizado, React no es consciente de estos cambios, lo que eventualmente generará inconsistencia entre lo que se muestra en pantalla y lo que React tiene en memoria.

Dos cosas importantes a destacar:

- Esto no es un problema específico de JQuery, sino de cualquier librería que uses (incluso con vanilla JS) al momento de modificar directamente el DOM.
- Esto tampoco implica que no puedas usar JQuery, solo debes ser cuidadoso de no usar funciones que modifiquen el DOM directamente.

Más info, puedes revisar la [documentación de React](https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html) sobre este tema.

Comment: Se entendió, gracias.